# Sending cron output to a file with a timestamp in its name

Tags: cron

I have a crontab like this on a LAMP setup:

```
0 0 * * * /some/path/to/a/file.php > $HOME/cron.log 2>&1
```

This writes the output of the file to *cron.log*. However, when it runs again, it overwrites whatever was previously in the file.

How can I get cron to **output to a file with a timestamp in its filename?**

An example filename would be something like this: *2010-02-26-000000-cron.log*

I don't really care about the format, as long as it has a timestamp of some kind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you don't want `$HOME/cron.log` to be overwritten, use `>>` not `>`

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Try:

```
0 0 * * * /some/path/to/a/file.php > $HOME/`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`-cron.log 2>&1
```

Play around with the date format, if you like; just be sure to escape any `%` like `\%`, as above.

Comment: And let me generally suggest an approach to file names like
`0 0 * * * /some/path/to/a/file.php > $HOME/scriptname-`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.log`

Comment: If you need it a little more human readable try: 
`date +\%Y\ \%m\ \%d\ \%H:\%M:\%S`-cron.log

Comment: @DevilCode, yes, although spaces in filenames aren't very conventional in Unix. Hyphens or underscores might be a better option: `date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M:\%S-cron.log`.

Comment: Those freaking escape characters always get me. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: This Note saved my life.
"Play around with the date format, if you like; just be sure to escape any % like \%, as above."

Answer (score 23):

I would highly recommend that you save everything into the same file, using timestamp, as [explained on Abdullah Diab’s Blog](http://mpcabd.xyz/adding-a-timestamp-to-command-output-in-linux/).

remove

> 2>&1

... and run it through the timestamping script before saving it to log file.

`timestamp.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read x; do
    echo -n `date +%d/%m/%Y\ %H:%M:%S`;
    echo -n " ";
    echo $x;
done
```

Remember to `chmod +x timestamp.sh` to make it executable.

Then edit the cron job line using `crontab -e` to be like this:

```
/path/to/my/command.sh 2>&1 | /path/to/timestap.sh >> /var/log/cron/my_log.log
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also append your output to the log file by doing it like this:

```
0 0 * * * /some/path/to/a/file.php >> $HOME/cron.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

I modified the script like this:

```
`/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d`.log
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem; just add the date path (/bin/date) before the date command.

Comment: Please add more info and example.

Answer (score -1):

```
@daily /some/path/to/a/file.php 2>&1 > $HOME/$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S)-cron.log
```

Comment: This would need a lot of explanation.