# sending cron log to a filename with timeststamp

Tags: cron

I'm trying to use below but it doesn't work:

```
*/3 * * * * java -jar /opt/Folder1/Utility.jar > /var/log/date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M:\%S-backup.log 2>&1
```

Could you pls guide where it went wrong?

ref: [Sending cron output to a file with a timestamp in its name](https://serverfault.com/questions/117360/sending-cron-output-to-a-file-with-a-timestamp-in-its-name)

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your cron job seems OK except that it is missing the back ticks `around the`date` command. You need to write the log file name as follows:

```
/var/log/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H:\%M:\%S`-backup.log
```